# How to allow file upload in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, file-upload, iis-7

I am using JQuery to upload files to a folder in my website's root folder via a file upload dialog on a page from the website.  This works fine when I run it locally using Casinni but fails when I deploy to a server which hosts the site using IIS 7.  Do I need to do anything in IIS to allow such file uploads?

Comment: have you checked the file permission? also send us the error.

Comment: What role is your worker process running as? Does it have permission to write to the local drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along these lines...

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<script runat="server">
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            try
            {
            FileUpload1.SaveAs("C:\\Uploads\\" + 
                 FileUpload1.FileName);
            Label1.Text = "File name: " +
                 FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName + "<br>" +
                 FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength + " kb<br>" +
                 "Content type: " +
                 FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Label1.Text = "ERROR: " + ex.Message.ToString();
        }
    else
    {
        Label1.Text = "You have not specified a file.";
    }
    }
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Upload Files</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" /><br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" 
         Text="Upload File" />&nbsp;<br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Another source of acquiring this "skill" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479405.aspx

Forget it.... misread the whole thing.